# Botón que me envíe a otra página html

Tags: php, html, apache

Estoy intentando hacer botones que me dirijan a otro html pero no me funcionan

```
 <div class="action-buttons">
    <a href="clientes/clientes1.html" class="btn-1">INGRESO</a>
    <a href="tiket/tiket_salida.hora.html" class="btn-1">Salida</a>
    <a href="tiket/tiket_salida.html" class="btn-1">GENERAR TIKET</a>
 </div>
```

[image: aca tengo imagen donde muesta mas o menos donde se ubican las otras paginas]

Comment: Buenas, Josue, bienvenido al sitio. No estoy familiarizado con ese IDE que usas, no sé como despliega en un servidor, que es probablemente donde esté el problema, que las rutas asociadas a tus botones no sean exactamente donde se hallen tus páginas. ¿Lo has comparado con otro proyecto donde sí funcionen? Por otro lado, tienes una errata que se repite mucho, "tiket" debería ser "ticket".

Comment: Son simples anclas con el estilo de un botón, no deberían darte problemas. Que errores te dan, tanto la web como el inspector??

Comment: En la imagen, los archivos de los `href` están en una carpeta distinta de donde está el archivo que contiene los enlaces. Dado que no sabemos cómo se renderiza eso en tu proyecto, debes revisarlo, sea en la misma barra del navegador, sea inspeccionando la consola. Si se renderizan tal cual, debes volver al directorio raíz y buscar los html en la carpeta donde están, algo del tipo: `href="../htpark/html_css/clientes/clientes1.html"`

Comment: Que error te muestra al presionar algún botón?

Answer (score 1):

Asumiendo que esto es un proyecto simple (no enrutadores, no renderizadores, etc), hay que tener en cuenta en dónde estás y hacia dónde vas, (rutas relativas).

Según la imagen, estás en `html_css/tiket/tiket.html`
Y quieres ir a las siguientes rutas:

```html
html_css/clientes/clientes1.html
html_css/tiket/tiket_salida.hora.html
html_css/tiket/salida.html
```

Entonces los enlaces en **tiket.html** deberían ser:

```html
<a href="../clientes/clientes1.html">INGRESO</a>
<a href="tiket_salida.hora.html">SALIDA</a>
<a href="salida.html">GENERAR TIKET</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Como dijo](/a/606409) [@aeportugal](/users/80870), es importante ver dónde está ubicado tu html (que está haciendo el request de redirección) y dónde están ubicados los archivos de destino.

En este caso como bien dijo @aeportugal, sería necesario usar *../carpeta/nombre.html* para que el archivo que está pidiendo la redirección pueda encontrar el archivo de destino.
Ya por último recalcar por si alguna vez te es necesario que el uso del `./` y `../` es el siguiente:

- `./` -> Para la carpeta actual
- `../` -> Para la carpeta anterior
- `../../` -> Tantos `../` como haya se desplaza a carpetas anteriores. (Ejemplo: *../../../index.html* se desplazará a 3 carpetas atrás).